# sbt to exclude source directory

Tags: scala, sbt

How do I config build.sbt to exclude src/main/java directory? I would like to put my Java sources there but I don't want to compile them. Also, can I exclude a file or group of files specify with RE. Can these be easily configured in build.sbt?

Comment: I'm curious, why don't you want the Java files to be compiled?

Comment: I wrote the application in Java and I rewrote the application in Scala. I still want the Java sources to be there as reference but not compile to save compilation time and dependency. No biggie, I can live with Java sources compiled. Also, I want to learn to tweak SBT as part of this exercise

Comment: If you're using a source code system like Subversion or git, you can delete with confidence. If you ever have to look at the Java code, it's only a few commands away from restoration (or a few clicks if you have a web interface setup on top of the scm).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`javaSource` and `scalaSource` are inputs to `unmanagedSourceDirectories`.  You can then set `unmanagedSourceDirectories` to be `scalaSource` only:

```
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile <<=
   scalaSource in Compile apply ( (s: File) => s :: Nil)
```

or a bit shorter:

```
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile <<= (scalaSource in Compile)( _ :: Nil)
```

See [Classpaths, sources, and resources](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Classpaths.html) for details.  Also, the [inspect](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Inspecting-Settings) command is useful for determining how settings are built up from other settings.

Answer (score 4):

Well, there might be a better way but I'd add this to my build.sbt:

`javaSource in Compile := file("some/path/that/doesnt/exist")`

Comment: Thanks. I am sure there is a better way :)