# How to exclude the java source directory using sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

What do I have to write on the `build.sbt` file to exclude the java files on my project from compiling and generate `.class` files? I was trying to use [the answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7456491/2096986) but it seems too old and things have changed for `sbt.version = 1.4.7`.

I tried to do something like this:

```
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile := { (scalaSource in Compile)( _ => Nil) }
```

But I am getting a type mismatch

```
found   : sbt.Def.Initialize[scala.collection.immutable.Nil.type]
required: Seq[java.io.File]
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile := { (scalaSource in Compile)( _ => Nil) }
^
[error] Type error in expression
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
Compile / unmanagedSourceDirectories := (Compile / scalaSource).value :: Nil
Test / unmanagedSourceDirectories := (Test / scalaSource).value :: Nil
```

as it is shown here: https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Java-Sources.html#Java+Sources